# Confusion with Action bar navigation - inner navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Im new to Action Bars, and have opted for ActionBar Sherlock as it can work on older Android models. I'm primarily an iOS developer so I apologise if I use some related terms.

I have three tabs with three seperate fragments, Fragment 1, Fragment 2, Fragment 3.

I can navigate between the three fragments using the `ActionBar Tabs` and `ViewPager`. I want to know whats the design to navigate within a fragment - for example, Fragment 1 has a button that leads to Fragment 1a when clicked on. Do I launch an intent to a new Activity or to a new Fragment? Or is there a different way to do it.

I would also like to keep a design that keeps the action bar with tabs on top containing Fragment 1, Fragment 2, and Fragment 3.

Sorry if i havent given enough information.

**Update**
Basically, how to replace Fragment 1 with Fragment 1a on a click of a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Android Developer documentation:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that information, so fragment transaction is the navigation process.

Answer (score -1):

From a fragment you may ask your activity to make a transition to other fragment. Switch to needed tab. See getActivity

Comment: so to go from Fragment1 to Fragment 1a I would use an intent to go to another Fragment(Fragment 1a)?